# how to make an extruded block having the same texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, node-editor, vector-mapping

im a beginner in 3d modeling on blender and when i put a texture on an extruded model, it seems to have a glitch or line/moving texture and some of the extruded block(the same block on the model) doesn't even have a texture. do I have to manually put the pattern? on each faces? [image: 1st pic][image: 2nd pic]

edit: iv'e relaunched it and it work just a bug, probably...

Comment: Hi there:). You just need to unwrap your entire mesh again. Its not a glitch. When u extrude an edge your texture just gets stretched

Comment: also, your topology on picture #2 doesn't seem very good

Comment: i forgot to say i unwraped it when I was finding some solution, but it did not work. probably just a bug or the unwrap triggers when I relaunched it .

Comment: anyway @moonboots I know hahaha i was getting rid of it